# How can I get a datetime hour in python for a specific timezone?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I have a UTC datetime but I need to get the numerical hour depending on any given timezone string, i.e: 'America/Los_Angeles'

I need a function that looks something like this:

```
def get_hour_timezone(utc_datetime, timezone):
    return utc_datetime.hour(AT_SPECIFIC_TIMEZONE)


get_hour_timezone(now(), 'America/Los_Angeles') # This should return 5, because it's 5 AM

get_hour_timezone(now(), 'UTC') # This should return 12, because it's 12 PM (7 hours past Los Angeles because it's utc)
```

I also need the same functions for month and day (In the event that its 11 PM Los Angeles time on the last day of the month, but 2 AM UTC time of the NEXT month)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to first convert the datetime to a specific timezone.

```
def get_datetime_with_timezone(dt, tz):
    local_timezone = timezone(tz)
    if dt.tzinfo is None:
        datetime_aware = local_timezone.localize(dt)
    else:
        datetime_aware = dt.astimezone(local_timezone)
    return datetime_aware
```